# Текст внутри тэга без учета текста внутри детей

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, dom

```
<div id="info">
<span class="trash">
trash info
</span>
info 123456
</div>
```

Надо извлечь "info 123456" DOM методами, так как регуляркой я уже извлекаю.
Что-то типа

```
$('#info').not("trash")
```

прокатит? У меня не получилось.

P.S. на спичках не экономлю, jquery только приветствую. Но для полноты картины хотелось бы и чистое решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть вот такое решение:

```
alert($("#info").clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

Эту последовательность лучше в функцию обернуть я думаю... Кроме alert() естественно :)
Ну я думаю вы меня поняли

Comment: А разве текст не является чилдреном? Он же тоже ребенок, хоть бы и текстнода.

Comment: @knes, текст "info 123456" не является чилдреном. а все остальные элементы в div'e мы удаляем, так что ничего лишнего при вызове .text() у нас не выводится.